# Socket.io takes more time in receiving message from Node server

Tags: blackberry, socket.io, blackberry-webworks

I am using socket.io to connect to a server using Blackberry os7 (BB curve) mobile. Message emit is working fine. But it is not receiving message at the right time. It takes up to 10 seconds. Sometimes works fast , sometimes very slow.
The same code is working fine in Blackberry 10 mobile. I am developing the application using Blackberry webworks(HTML5).

Comment: How are you connecting to the network on the BBOS device?  Is it going through the WiFi transport only, or are you going to Cell direct, or is it through a corporate BES?  10 seconds seems like a very long time, however I'm curious whether there is something in the network that might be slowing it down.

Comment: I am using Wifi Network to connect to BBOS device. Yes it is going through wifi only. However in BBOS 9300  it is working fine. No idea why in BBOS Curve. I can also share the code if  required